# How do I just display plain numbers using SwiftUI? Text keeps adding commas

Tags: text, swiftui, number-formatting

I have been having an issue and have spent days trying to find a solution, I'm trying to learn SwiftUI having not done Swift in a while and only getting back into it post neurosurgery to remove  brain tumour (so maybe I'm just a bit slow). I'd spend a bit of time trying to solve this then give up and move on only to come back to it, but I'm reaching the point where I need it sorted as little else needs done in my app update / conversion to SwiftUI.

I am trying to display a year (eg 2021) output as just a number off some previous code I did, this is not handled as a date for a reason I won't get into here. I'm just passing years as numbers. However when I put these into Text() in the middle of a string they are always output formatted like a normal number (eg 2,021) which obviously is not how years are displayed.

Basically what I need is just a way to tell Text() to ignore the fact it's a "number" and just display it as is with no adaption as if it is just string value as part of the string it's being added to.

Example

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let theYear = 2021
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("The year is \(theYear)")
            }
      }
}
```

Will output

> The year is 2,021

I've tried to solve this but I'm clearly missing something that I'm sure is an obvious answer, anyone have any tips or advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just wrap it in a String().

```
Text("The year is \(String(theYear))")
```

Comment: Oh my goodness me! Thank you so much! You see I knew I must have just wandered off down the wrong train of thought and the swarm of tutorials online just didn't get me on the right path! I am incredibly grateful for this as it has sorted it instantly! Thank you!